# Разделение объекта на несколько

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том чтобы разделить текста, которые в теге `p`.

У меня есть объект:

```
let text = {text: "<p>Hello world 1</p><p>Hello world 2</p><p>Hello world 3</p>"}
```

На выходе мне надо получить:

```
let newObject = ['Hello world 1', 'Hello world 2', 'Hello world 3']
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш пример объекта некорректен. Объект должен иметь КЛЮЧ и ЗНАЧЕНИЕ.

Пример объекта:

```
const myObject = { text: "<p>Hello world 1</p><p>Hello world 2</p><p>Hello world 3</p>" }
```

Давайте теперь сделаем массив по вашему примеру.

```
// Сделаем массив
const myArray = myObject.text.split("<p>").join("").split("</p>");
// Удалим последний элемент массива
myArray.pop(myArray.length-1);
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
var s = "<p>Hello world 1</p><p>Hello world 2</p><p>Hello world 3</p>"
console.log([...new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, 'text/html').querySelectorAll('p')].map(p => p.textContent))
```

Comment: Ё-моё!.. И как это я `DOMParser()` пропустил?.. Метода давнишняя и поддержка норм. Спасибо. Пошёл изучать